# Does each virtual host has it's own default application (i. e. ROOT) in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I searched for this a lot but couldn't find the answer. [Tomcat documentation on virtual hosting](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) explains the example on a Host that is set as default for that Engine.
So that makes me wonder if you can only have a single default application or a ROOT.war or ROOT folder for each Engine or each Host element can have their own default application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can each have their own default application, you just have to specify which it is. From a security perspective I disagree with creating unnecessary root applications.

A thread will be spawned for each Application on each host. so three engines with three hosts using the same ROOT you will have nine instances of ROOT running.

Comment: Are you suggesting that ROOT for each host must be the same application or you're just making an example and each ROOT can be a different application?

Comment: Each ROOT can be the same or different applications, you just have to specify it in the config.